# How can I add a range item with grid click on vis.js

Tags: vis.js

I am new to vis.js and would like to modify the default add item click on timeline grid to make it create a range item of one hour length. Is this possible please.
          // Configuration for the Timeline

```
  var options = {
    stack: true,
    // display in UTC
    moment: function(date) {
        return vis.moment(date).utc();
    },
    start: today1,
    end: today2,
    editable: true,
        snap: function (date, scale, step) {
            var minit = 60 * 1000;
            return Math.round(date / minit) * minit;
        },
    orientation: 'top',
    showCurrentTime: false,

        onAdd: function (items, callback) {
          prettyPrompt('Add item', 'Enter text content for new item:', items.content, function (value) {
            if (value) {
              items.content = value;
              callback(items); // send back adjusted new item
            }
            else {
              callback(null); // cancel item creation
            }
          });
        },

        onUpdate: function (items, callback) {
          prettyPrompt('Update item', 'Edit items text:', items.content, function (value) {
            if (value) {
              items.content = value;
              callback(items); // send back adjusted item
            }
            else {
              callback(null); // cancel updating the item
            }
          });
        }


  };
```

Comment: This is possible. What have you tried so far? Do you have some code you can include in your question so that people can help you more effectively?

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {

//Add new item when double click
onAdd: function (item, callback) {

        //Name new item
        item.content = prompt('Task :', item.content);

        //Get current timeline time click
        currentTimeline = timeline.getEventProperties(event);
        startDate = currentTimeline.time;
        tempDay = new Date(startDate);
        endDate = tempDay.setDate(tempDay.getDate() + 3);
        item.start = startDate;
        item.end = endDate;

        //Add item
        if (item.content != null) {
            callback(item); //Sendback adjusted item
        } else {
            callback(null); //Cancel update item
        };

    }
};
```

Comment: Please describe your code in 1-2 minimal sentences.